# Max Value of Date Parameter as Sysdate or Today's date Jaspersoft

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have start date & end date as the input parameter . `Enddate`  should  be <= to `Sysdate` or Today's date.

In input control properties , how can enter the Max date as Today's date or `sysdate`   . Image URL showing where I am trying to put it.

Please let me know if we have any work around.
[image]

Comment: You can set default value for parameter

Comment: @AlexK Thanks for the answer. Your answer does help achieving what is required, in a way. I am looking for the user to be able to get the satisfaction that they cannot pick a future date. I hope this makes sense. thanks again.